MultipartFile to base64 including type and name
For some technical contraints I have to send and receive multipartfile data (small files size not a problem) with post rest encapsulated in base64 string.
I must verify file type (pdf) and file name after have decoded base64 string to multipartfile
I'm able to do this partial due to getBytes of multipartfile : only content is provided not full multipartfile objet.
I can't create a custom object I must deal with string and multipartfile (base64)
Could you help me two find the solution ?
I only have 24 hours...
Thanks and sorry for my english

getBytes function of multipartfile provide only content or the file not name and extension

"A filename is a variable name and length outside of its contents" that why I need of the entire MultipartFile objet to be encoded/decoded from/to base64

Its a standard MultipartFile in a Spring boot app. Please let me know the required information

File file = new File("./pdf.pdf");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Path.get("./pdf.pdf"));
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("pdf","pdf.pdf", "application/pdf", content);
String string = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(multipartFile .getBytes()));
multipartFile .getBytes() doesn't contain type and name only pdf content in bytes (I'm able to read decoded contant with transferTo override from a class which implements MultipartFile
